# Unable to create a select query with using json column?

Tags: postgresql

I want to create a select query that gives me the result for the customers having the pincode 99997, in the json below from the PostgreSQL table.

Json used:

```
{
    "user_address": [
        {
            "house_number": "123",
            "house_address": "abc Colony",
            "city": "XYZ",
            "state": "PQR",
            "pincode": "99999"
        },
        {
            "house_number": "456",
            "house_address": "mop Colony",
            "city": "BKW",
            "state": "MAH",
            "pincode": "99997"
        },
        {
            "house_number": "789",
            "house_address": "poui Colony",
            "city": "XYZ",
            "state": "PQR",
            "pincode": "99989"
        },
        {
            "house_number": "879",
            "house_address": "rty Colony",
            "city": "BKW",
            "state": "MAH",
            "pincode": "99997"
        }
    ]
}
```

already tried using the index option which gives the json inside the "user_address".

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `json_array_elements` function present in the [PostgreSQL JSON](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html) data type to query the data

```
SELECT *
FROM   test t, json_array_elements(t.address->'user_address') obj
WHERE  obj->>'pincode' = '99997';
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/48588/2)

Answer (score 0):

You don't give a version, but this is relatively straightforward with postgres 12. If your table is called test, with a jsonb column named "a":

```
SELECT user_address 
FROM test 
CROSS JOIN LATERAL jsonb_path_query(a, 
                                    '$.user_address[*] ? (@.pincode == $pincode)', 
                                    '{"pincode":"99997"}') 
  as j(user_address);
                                               user_address
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 {"city": "BKW", "state": "MAH", "pincode": "99997", "house_number": "456", "house_address": "mop Colony"}
 {"city": "BKW", "state": "MAH", "pincode": "99997", "house_number": "879", "house_address": "rty Colony"}
(2 rows)
```